# Do I have to set up the BIOS on a new HDD/SSD? If so, how?

Tags: boot, grub2, bios

I want to install an SSD in my old laptop that runs Lubuntu but I don't really understand the BIOS. Is the BIOS specific to the hardware, meaning I'll need the same one as came on the HDD? Or will the USB install handle the BIOS for a new and blank SSD? Is the BIOS even on the HDD or is it saved somewhere else?

Having failed to find a simple answer I feel like I'm probably misunderstanding something quite a bit. Any links to a general explanation are also welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The BIOS ("Basic Input Output System") is every computer's built-in firmware.

It's located on a small Flash or EEPROM chip directly on your mainboard. Normally this chip is not removable nowadays.

Its purpose is to start booting the computer and initialize all the hardware so far that it can hand over the control to your operating system's boot loader (e.g. GRUB for Ubuntu), which is stored on one of your hard disks.

That means you normally don't have to worry about the BIOS. You can't lose it, especially not from changing a HDD.

Comment: Ok thanks, that makes life a lot easier as I wanted to do a lot of drive switching while experimenting.

Comment: Will do - for the sake of competition I just plan to wait an hour! ;)